# Draw owner drawn combobox "at once" instead of itemwise

Tags: windows, winapi, combobox, ownerdrawn

I am working on an owner drawn combobox. I process `WM_DRAWITEM` for each item, i.e. I draw to the device context for each item separately.

I would like to draw some UI elements "across multiple items" (e.g. a frame spanning two or more consecutive items).

So I thought about "accumulating" drawing commands in the `WM_DRAWITEM` handlers, and executing these commands once all of them are accumulated. I hoped that windows issues one message before all the `WM_DRAWITEM` and one message after all of them, but could not find any such window message, let alone details on the painting order of items. Does Windows offer infrastructure to do what I would like to do?

Comment: No. This wouldn't make sense, either, since the device context passed to your `WM_DRAWITEM` handler is clipped to the item you are painting. If you want to render visual state, that spans several items, you are responsible for maintaining that state yourself.

Comment: I am not sure if I really get your point. Imagine that there was a message in the spirit of `WM_AFTER_ALL_DRAWITEM` which would offer a device context *for the whole list*. In this case, I could easily ignore the device context of each `WM_DRAWITEM`, and take the device context of `WM_AFTER_ALL_DRAWITEM` to paint everything I have "collected" before.

Comment: But what would be the benefit? The rendering code would be identical for the coalesced rendering as if you painted each item individually. And since a combo box displays individual items per row, you shouldn't expect the control to be optimized for the unusual case (e.g. combining several rows' columns).

Comment: The rendering code would not necessarily be identical. Imagine that you want to draw a diagonal line covering the whole list (for whatever reasons). I think in this case a collect-and-draw-once approach would be beneficial, since you do not need the subpart of the diagonal line for each item, but can instead paint the whole diagonal at once.

Comment: You don't have to render the hypothetical diagonal piecewise. Just render it exactly as you would in your collect-and-draw-once algorithm. Clipping makes sure, that it only shows up in the item currently being rendered.

Comment: Sub-class and handle `WM_PAINT` and `WM_PRINTCLIENT`, maybe.